# Recursion with replace() in java

Tags: java, recursion, replace

I'm busy learning recursion in java and I have a task with replace in recursion, I have the following method, that works and now I want to change into a recursion.

```
public class replaceWith {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     System.out.println(replaceWith("Hallo World" , "ll","@@"));


 }


 public static String replaceWith(String str1, String str2, String str3)
 {

         return str1.replaceAll(str2, str3);
 }
```

}
The above code works, below is my code for recursion replace()

```
public class replaceWith {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     System.out.println(replaceWith("Hallo World" , "ll","@@"));


 }

 public static String replaceWith(String str1, String str2, String str3)
 {

     if (str1.length() <=1)

         return str1;
     else
         return replaceWith(str1.replaceAll(str2, str3));
 }
```

}

I get a error on my last return which reads:
"The method replaceWith(STring, String, String)in the type replaceWith is not applicable for the arguments(String)"

What will the reason be for this?

Comment: why does this need to be recursive? replace/replaceAll replace all occurrences in the string

Comment: It's just how they ask the task to do it in recursive :)

Comment: Unless you are replacing all chars with `""` then `if (str1.length() <=0)` will never be true

Comment: O yes sorry that should be 1?

Answer (score 1):

> "The method replaceWith(STring, String, String)in the type replaceWith is not applicable for the arguments(String)"

Because replaceWith needs 3 parameters but you are passing only one.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive call `return replaceWith(str1.replaceAll(str2, str3));` contains one String parameter but the replaceWith function contains three String parameters. There is a mismatch in the number of arguments in the recursive call